# Not receiving Emails on Google App Engine

Tags: php, email, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I've followed the [receiving mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mail/sending-receiving-with-mail-api) instructions to create the following `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

inbound_services:
- mail

handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: handle_incoming_email.php
  login: admin
```

my `handle_incoming_email.php` is similarly compact with:

```
<?php
syslog(LOG_INFO, 'hello from handle_incoming_email');
```

running in `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` and sending mail via `http://localhost:8000/mail` i get a succes message in that dev server interface and my console logs show:

> INFO: hello from handle_incoming_email
>
> INFO     2018-02-22 23:13:33,985 module.py:835] default: "POST /_ah/mail/anything@example.com HTTP/1.1" 200 555

however, deploying to app engine and sending mails from two different accounts with double checking the email address, neither POSTS to /_ah/mail nor my log message with show up in the logs.

Comment: You receive mail in the app at a `string@project_id.appspotmail.com` address.  Not a `anything@example.com` address.

Comment: Yes. I also suspect you are not using the right email address. [Check its format here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mail/sending-receiving-with-mail-api#receiving_mail). You have to be carefull with the **appid** part

Comment: hi, so i've checked the format multiple times. on the Deployed server im using the correct format (such as string@xxx-project-id-xx.appspotmail.com). The anything@example.com above works with the development server because the form there allows any "from" adress to initiate the post request for `/_ah/mail/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out:

I had the Identity-Aware Proxy (beta) enabled under https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iap/

It appears the email service can not pass through this proxy. I've filed a bug report at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73787787